# Adding second argument in a C++ function prevents OpenGL from drawing?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have this function "cameraControl(const float& movementVleocity)" that does nothing... I mean:

```
inline void controlCamera(const float& movementVelocity)
{

}
```

... and I call it like this in the main loop:

```
basicCamera.controlCamera(2.0);
```

And everything is fine... my model draws and it goes okay, UNTILL... I add a second argument like this:

```
inline void controlCamera(const float& movementVelocity, const float& cameraVelocity)
{

}
```

... and call it like this in the main loop:

```
basicCamera.controlCamera(2.0, 2.0);
```

And  get a black screen... my model doesn't show anymore...
This makes absolutely no sense in any way I can relate to...

EDIT:

camera.h

```
#ifndef CAMERA_H_INCLUDED
#define CAMERA_H_INCLUDED

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/rotate_vector.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace glm;

class camera
{
    public:
        camera(const vec3& position, const float& fieldOfView, const float& aspectRatio, const float& nearestDistance,
                const float& furtherDistance, const vec3& cameraForward, const vec3& cameraUp)
        {
            m_cameraPosition = position;
            m_cameraForward = cameraForward;
            m_cameraUp = cameraUp;
            m_cameraYaw = 0.0;
            m_cameraPitch = 0.0;

            m_perspective = perspective(fieldOfView, aspectRatio, nearestDistance, furtherDistance);
        }

        inline void lockCamera()
        {
            if(m_cameraYaw < 0)
                m_cameraYaw += 360;
            if(m_cameraYaw > 360)
                m_cameraYaw -= 360;
            if(m_cameraPitch > 90)
                m_cameraPitch = 90;
            if(m_cameraPitch < -90)
                m_cameraPitch = -90;
        }

        inline void moveCameraHorizontal(const float& direction, const float& distance)
        {
            m_cameraPosition.x = sinf(m_cameraYaw + direction) * distance;
            m_cameraPosition.z = cosf(m_cameraPitch + direction) * distance;
        }

        inline void moveCameraVertical(const float& direction, const float& distance)
        {
            m_cameraPosition.y = sinf(m_cameraPitch + direction) * distance;
        }

        inline void controlCamera(const float& movementVelocity, const float& cameraVelocity)
        {

        }

        inline mat4 getViewPerspective() const
        {
            return m_perspective * lookAt(m_cameraPosition, m_cameraPosition - m_cameraForward, m_cameraUp);
        }

    private:
        mat4 m_perspective;
        vec3 m_cameraPosition;
        vec3 m_cameraForward;
        vec3 m_cameraUp;
        float m_cameraYaw;
        float m_cameraPitch;
};

#endif // CAMERA_H_INCLUDED
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    // Initialize GLFW.
    if(!glfwInit())
    {
        cout << "GLFW could not initialize." << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Create window.
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "add_mesh_class", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLEW.
    GLuint err = glewInit();
    if(err != GLEW_OK)
    {
        cout << "GLEW could not initialize." << endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Model data.
    mesh model_mesh("models/sky_ship.obj");
    float model_rotation = 0.0;

    // Initialize shaders.
    shader basicShader("shaders/basic");
    basicShader.useShader();

    // Initialize texture.
    texture model_texture("textures/red_lines.jpg");
    model_texture.useTexture(0);

    // Transformation class.
    transform mvTransform;

    // Camera class.
    camera basicCamera(vec3(0.0, 0.0, -5.0), 70, WINDOW_WIDTH / WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0.1, 1000.0, vec3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0), vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));

    // Main loop.
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Logic.
        model_rotation += 0.02;

        // Camera.
        basicCamera.lockCamera();
        basicCamera.controlCamera(2.0f, 2.0f);

        // Render.
        mvTransform.setRotation(model_rotation, vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
        mvTransform.setTranslation(vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        basicShader.update(mvTransform, basicCamera);
        model_mesh.draw();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without seeing the real code.

Comment: how is it "not fine"?

Comment: Isnt it problem of float/double passed via x87 registers? Try to cast arguments to floats (from doubles) basicCamera.controlCamera(2.0f, 2.0f);

Comment: @Anonymous I highly doubt that, that's just one of those things C++ will just implicitly convert for you

Comment: I tried to cast it already and its not working... well... my code is 700 lines in total which part do you need? Proably just the camera.h and main.cpp files?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What happens?? I mean, you forgot to actually tell us the problem.

Comment: It's probably a case of undefined behavior. The error is elsewhere in the code. Adding the extra parameter moves things around in memory and gives a different result.

Comment: Is there any other definition of controlCamera() so compiler may choose another "forgotten" implementation? Did you try to remove inline thing?

Comment: @narutkataaa the error simply does not appear to occur in the snippets you posted (since just pasting these into an empty file obviously will not cause an error) and it's hard for us to guess how the rest of your code looks.

Comment: I found something - if i run it in debug mode opengl draws my model. What are the differences by running in debug mode and building and running?

Comment: Are you making sure that all dependent files are recompiled when you change the definition in the header? Maybe try a clean build just in case?

Comment: Did a clean build and everything compiles and same result - in debug the model shows but when i build and run it doesnt.

Comment: Why are you passing `const` references to a `float` in the first place? Surely passing the value would be no less efficient, in fact on some architectures passing a reference might take up more space on the callstack (e.g. x86-64) than an actual single-precision `float`.

Comment: In fact, I'm not so sure it's a great idea to pass a constant expression to a function that expects a reference. If you ditch the reference passing design and pass two floats by value, does the problem go away?

Comment: Yes, the problem does go away. But I have other functions and I pass to reference arguments the same way... why doesn't this error occur?

Comment: Constant expressions don't have addresses, so the compiler has to do some magic behind the scenes to give **2.0** and **2.0** addresses so you can pass them by reference. If you passed references to two constant variables (e.g. `float x = 2.0f; float y = 2.0f;`) it is likely the problem would also go away. As far as I know, there's nothing wrong with passing *constant* references to constant expressions, but I have encountered compilers that do weird things when you try this.

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly be a memory corruption bug, and by adding the extra parameter you are subtly changing the layout of data in memory and causing the bug to have a visible effect, where before you were getting away with it - i.e. you were still overwriting memory, but happened to be overwriting something unimportant.

Normally your function would be removed by the compiler because it does nothing, however I'm guessing you are compiling in debug mode and so it may not optimize it away.

Comment: The function did some stuff, but I deleted it line by line to find out where the problem is... and it turned out that more than 1 argument causes the problem... Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately if this is the problem, the error could lie pretty much anywhere in your code.  Check all your memory allocations and pointer accesses to make sure you're not stepping off the end of an array or something like that.

Comment: Is there a way to debug? I have 700 lines of code... and isn't writing in RAM random? How come I only overwrite the same place everytime?

Comment: No it's not random, the compiler will chose where to place the memory.  Suppose you have two variables declared consecutively, an 8 byte array followed by an int.  The compiler will mostly likely place them consecutively in memory.  If you then try to write to byte number 9 of the array, you'll end up modifying the int.